# State changing but component not re rendering react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a functional component in React with Typescript. I'm using redux with redux thunk. I have a form for logging in user which sends a request to my API. My form's working fine, the state is updating but the component is not re-rendering when the state changes. Let's get to the code.

Store:

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { authReducer } from './reducers/users';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
});

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));

export default store;
```

reducer:

```js
import { USER_LOGOUT, USER_SIGNIN, USER_SIGNUP } from '../constants/user';
import { IAction } from '../interfaces/global';

export const authReducer = (state = {}, action: IAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_SIGNUP:
            return Object.assign(action.payload);
        case USER_SIGNIN:
            return { ...action.payload, test: 'A' };
        case USER_LOGOUT:
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Action:

```js
export const signin = (data: { email: string; password: string }) => async (dispatch: Function) => {
    try {
        const { data: auth }: AxiosResponse<IResponseSuccess> = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/users/signin`, data);

        dispatch({
            type: USER_SIGNIN,
            payload: { ...auth.data },
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_SIGNIN,
            payload: { error: error.response.data.error },
        });
    }
};
```

Finally, where I have dispatched the action:

```js
    const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Some Validation for form which is ommited


        // Dispatch
        dispatch(signin(formData));
    };
```

I've been struggling for over the past few hours and I'd appreciate any help/tips. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would your component need to re render? I don't see any code in your question that would suggest a component that re renders when state would change. The reducer and actions look fine so if you confirmed everything works fine (redux devtools) then you should have a look at the selector. Make sure your component selects the right data.

Comment: return Object.assign(action.payload) seems wrong, but that’s not the case that’s giving your problems, right?  Also it’s unusual to have the same action type for success and failure actions.  And you don’t change the state at all on logout? So there’s lots of weird things.  What part of your state does the component access?

Comment: I actually have an alert system that depends on the response. I'll work on the actions part. @LindaPaiste If you notice, actually the action which is being used is using destructuring. I was experimenting with the reducer so its object.assign

Comment: object.assign is used to copy properties from one object to another.  It doesn’t make sense to call it with just one object argument https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Ok, it still does not solve my rendering issue